# Stop some subdomains xxx.xxx.com of a single website being indexed by search engines

Tags: robots.txt, noindex

I need to stop indexing subdomains of a same site, for example:

1. `aaa.xxx.com`: (No indexing)
2. `bbb.xxx.com`: (No indexing)
3. `www.xxx.com`: (It should indexed)

All the subdomains are under the same domain. How can we achive that?

Answer (score 1):

On the subdomain you don't want indexed, include a robots.txt file in the main web directory that contains:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

On the subdomain you want to index, don't do anything